# How to change an expiring CA certificate issued by letsencrypt to a new root CA of other than letsencrypt?

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, lets-encrypt

I was using a letsencrypt certificate for the https connection, but now the DST root CA X3 is getting expired and they added a new path to the root ISRG X1, which is not a trusted root for the IoT device that I'm using. So I need to change the root certificate in my server to a new one. Can anyone help me with a solution on how the new certificate can be added along with the existing one or without the existing one. I'm using nginx in an ubuntu EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

The nginx configuration directives `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` need to be updated to point to your new files. See [the documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for more detailed information.

Comment: When Sectigo expired this was used to fix the chain (not that is needed since openssl was fixed to conform RFC 4158) https://whatsmychaincert.com/